# How to write ContentProvider if database is in sdcard\*\?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to know how the Uri of the ContentProvider accurately point to a database.
In the example provided in the development documentation, the database is created by SQLiteOpenHelper with the default path `\data\data\`.
However, due to special demands, I have to put the database on this path: `\sdcard\pdm\pdm.db`, then how to write the corresponding **Uri** and **authorities**, and how do I know it accurately point to my database?

Comment: **authority** and the whole `Uri` can be anything you want, there is no correlation with it and your database path

Comment: Indeed. But i would formulate it different: you can keep authority and the whole uri the same. Only change that base path in your code.

Comment: however if he use the uri from `"the example provided in the development documentation"` i dont think it would be a good solution...

Comment: Hmm... I dont know ..  You will be rigth. I did not look .. So i will never know why ;-).